# How to Test Deleting collections in firebase emulator (firebase_tools.firestore.delete talks to cloud, not emulator)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am attempting to test a firebase cloud function in the emulator.  I've been able to CRUD firestore data in the emulator.   I am able to call cloud functions in the emulator.  But my function that deletes a collection is reaching out to google cloud rather than perform the action in the emulator.

To delete a collection, google recommends you use "firebase_tools" to perform the action (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

Here is the simplified version of my cloud function running in the emulator:

```
//Delete a firestore document.  
//When run in the emulator, this will successfully delete the piece of data in our emulator.
const paPath = FirebasePathUtils.getTeamPropertyAnalysisPath(pa.parentTeamId, pa.parentWorkspaceId, pa.id);
const p1 = admin.firestore().doc(paPath).delete();

//Delete all data in a collection.  
//When run in the emulator this IS REACHING OUT TO THE REAL CLOUD NOT USING THE EMULATOR.
const paDataPath = FirebasePathUtils.getTeamPropertyAnalysisDataPath(teamId, wsId, paId);
const pa2 = firebase_tools.firestore
   .delete(paDataPath, {
     project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
     recursive: true,
     yes: true,
     token: functions.config().fb.token
   })
   .then( () => {
     console.log(`Successfully Deleted data under ${paDataPath}`);
   });

return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
```

When I run the cloud function in the emulator, and execute the delete collection code using "firebase_toosl" I get the output

```
Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/reitools-test/databases/(default)/documents/teamdata/-LjcN--jRrirOzDD0e3I/workspace_data/-LjcN-vktqOC8BJR_8X1/property_analyses_data/-LgJZf7GLRetC2fsVRvb"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/reitools-test/databases/(default)/documents/teamdata/-LjcN--jRrirOzDD0e3I/workspace_data/-LjcN-vktqOC8BJR_8X1/property_analyses_data/-LgJZf7GLRetC2fsVRvb:runQuery"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
```

Any ideas on how to get "firebase_tools" to perform it's actions against the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I see that that it's been 8 month since you post your question. I hope that you already solved your problem.

If not and for those who land here, the problem is with your environment variable "process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT".

I believe in your test you are initializing a emulated firestore instance like that :

```
firebase.initializeAdminApp({ projectId: 'deletetest' }).firestore()
```

In this case your should overwrite the GCLOUD_PROJECT variable with 'deletetest' which is the projectId of your emulated project instance.

It is as simple as

```
process.env.PROJECT_ID = 'deleteclub'
```

And I think that with Jest the variable will only be overwritten for the test file so if other tests need this environment variable it will not cause any issues and off course you will need to overwrite it for each test where needed.

I hope this will make someone happy :)

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The delete is still applied on production data (thanks got it's only dummy data).

Answer (score 0):

This may be EXTREMELY late but I was struggling with this problem recently and I came to the conclusion that it may not be possible (yet) to test cloud functions against an emulator (though I could be wrong).

But if you just want to test your cloud functions, unit tests are the way to go. My solution was to create a second 'dev' project in Firebase.
In my index.js, I initialize the admin with empty params:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
admin.initializeApp()
```

Then in my unit test file (index.test.js), I initialize my test environment with the serviceAccountKey I downloaded from my second 'dev' project. (in firebase console, find project settings, then service accounts tab, then generate new serviceAccountKey)

```
const test = require("firebase-functions-test")({ 
    databaseURL: "'https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "your-project-id",
}, "path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
```

The tests all perform their work on the live 'dev' database, which is NOT upgraded to the blaze plan. However, since the serviceAccountKey is only in the index.test.js file, when I run `firebase deploy`, the functions (and security rules) deploy to my production project.

Thus I get all the benefits of unit testing without having to worry about ruining my production database. And since the spark plan has such generous read/write limits, I doubt my dev project will ever be in danger of exceeded them.

If you did find a way to test cloud functions purely in an emulator, please let me know. And if you haven't found a solution yet, I hope the option I provided helps.

P.S. `firestore.recursiveDelete(docRef)` is for sure the better way to delete collections (and subCollections).

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#recursiveDelete

Answer (score -1):

```js
import * as http from 'http'

// Adapted from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/00235ba68fdbb5d9788a14ba2bdd75cad87301e4/packages/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/test_environment.ts#L105

export const clearFirestore(projectName: string) = async (): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve: () => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => {
    http
      .request(
        {
          protocol: 'http:',
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: '9000',
          path: `/emulator/v1/projects/${projectName}/databases/(default)/documents`,
          method: 'DELETE',
        },
        function (res) {
          if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            resolve()
          } else {
            reject(`clearFirestore() failed: ${res.statusCode}`)
          }
        }
      )
      .on('error', (e) => {
        reject(e)
      })
      .end()
  })
}
```